# What does `Reported from` mean in the Kiali Dashboard for Inbound Metrics and Outbound Metrics?

Tags: tcp, istio, kiali

I am trying to understand the TCP traffic between my deployments in Kiali but few of the Tabs are a little confusing to me.

From what I understand --

- Inbound traffic - refers to traffic flowing from the Workload to other nodes
- Outbound traffic - refers to incoming traffic from Workloads to this node

Then there are sub-options for `Reported from` - Source / Destination in both of them. What does that mean?

I am getting two different graphs for Inbound traffic when I change the `Reported from` value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subtelty of Istio telemetry. Basically, all metrics are reported redundantly both by the source of a request and by the destination, regardless whether it is inbound or outbound. See the `reporter` label definition here: https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/metrics/#labels

Most of the time this information is redundant, that is it will be the same for `source` and `destination` reporters, but in several cases it will differ, for instance:

- When the request emitter is not part of the service mesh, hence vizualized as `unknown`, there will be no corresponding telemetry for that `source`.
- Similarly, if the receiver is `unknown` there will be no corresponding telemetry for that `destination`.
- Some Istio features impact this telemetry, for instance when Fault Injection is enabled the corresponding telemetry will be emitted for `source` but not for `destination`. Similar things happens whenever a request is canceled from the outbound sidecar, e.g. with circuit breaking or such.
- On the contrary, when mirroring is configured the mirrored requests will be seen for `destination` reporter but not for `source`
- The `response time` metric differs depending on reporter: on `source` reporting it accounts for the whole response time, i.e. server processing time + network roundtrip whereas in `destination` reporting it will account only for the server processing time, hence you will see lower values.

That's all I can think about now, but there's probably other exceptions.